# Javascript - How to convert string '0' to number 0

Tags: javascript, numbers, frontend, parseint, string-conversion

I'm trying to do error handling on 2 input values. I'm using regex to confirm that the input is always a number. The issue I'm having is that I don't want my error handling to kick in if the user literally inputs 0. Right now I'm using:

```
number = parseInt(incomingValue) || ""
```

to set my variable. The issue is that this turns `'0'` into `""`

Its fine if an empty value becomes an empty string because I am disabling my error checking when the lengths are equal to `0`, but I need to properly turn `'0'` into a number `0`. Anyone have any ideas?

Additionally, I'd also like to turn `'000'` (and so forth) into a number `0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Answer (score 4):

You can turn '0' or '000' into a number by just doing:

```
parseInt('0');   // 0
parseInt('000'); // 0
```

The reason your code is not working is that javascript treats `0` as a falsly value, so when you do this:

```
const number = parseInt('0') || ""
```

the expression `parseInt('0')` will return `0` which is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). As a result, the `|| ""` will be executed which will set `number` to `""`. You'll need to separate your `parseInt` and your default assignment to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the logic to account for empty values elsewhere and it properly handles 0 now

Answer (score 1):

Use **"Number()"**:

```js
console.log(Number('0'));
console.log(Number('000'));

console.log(typeof(Number('0')));
console.log(typeof(Number('000')));
```

Or put **"+"** before **'0'** and **'000'**:

```js
console.log(+'0');
console.log(+'000');

console.log(typeof(+'0'));
console.log(typeof(+'000'));
```

Or put **`"* 1"`** before or after **'0'** and **'000'**:

```js
console.log('0' * 1);
console.log('000' * 1);

console.log(typeof('0' * 1));
console.log(typeof('000' * 1));
```

Comment: I'd stick with suggesting `Number(...)`. The rest is more strange language feature abuse

Comment: Yes, I agree with you! "Number(...)" is more clear and more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseInt(incomingValue)` to get the `int` value.
For comparing you can use `===` for equal value and equal type means `(incomingValue === 0)` will be `true` in case of `incomingValue = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typeof to distinguish what type of variable you are receiving

typeof true === 'boolean'

typeof null === 'object'

typeof 62 === 'number'

typeof 'Hello World' === 'string'